# error installing fink on MacOs 10 "10.13 does not match the expected value"

Tags: fink

This question has been asked before with exactly the same error message without any answer so I'm reposting the question...

Currently trying to install fink on my MacBookAir high Sierra, following the instructions on:
https://www.finkproject.org/download/index.php?phpLang=en
this error has displayed after I have written the ./bootstrap command in the fink-3.28.0 directory created after unpacking:

Checking package...UNIVERSAL->import is deprecated and will be removed in a future perl at /Users/nelly/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Checksum.pm line 27.
looks good (fink-0.28.0).
Checking system... i386-apple-darwin17.7.0
Use of uninitialized value $darwin_osx in numeric eq (==) at /Users/nelly/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
Use of uninitialized value $darwin_osx in concatenation (.) or string at /Users/nelly/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
Argument "10.13 does not match the expected value of . Please run ..." isn't numeric in exit at /Users/nelly/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.

I tried to read the source code at the line given in the message but I still haven't been able to find the right modification to do.

Thanks for answering or giving any clue!